# How to write XML path expression for the following code?

Tags: xpath

Write an expression that selects all the items ISBN and TITLE that their return
is “3/12/2017”

**Code -**

`<itemlist>
   <item>
      <title>
         The Bonfire of the Vanities
      </title>
      <type>Book</type>
      <authors>
         <author>Wolfe, Tom</author>
      </authors>
      <subjects>
         <subject>New York</subject>
         <subject>Race Relations</subject>
      </subjects>
      <isbn>0374115370</isbn>
      <location>Adult</location>
      <collection>Fiction</collection>
      <status return="3/12/2017">Checked Out</status>
   </item>
</itemlist>`

Comment: /itemlist/item/status[@return='3/12/2017'] by using this expression i can only get the status elements attribute value but how can i get the title and isbn for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//itemlist/item[status/@return='3/12/2017']/(isbn|title)
```

Find item elements whose status element child has return attribute that is "3/12/2017", then take those items' children that are isbn or title elements.

Comment: thank you amadan..its working..how to select all items information which their
publisher is located in “New York” (the “New York” is a part of the publisher data) for the following: <itemlist>
   <item>
      <title>
         Real Family Food
      </title>
      <publisher>All You Books, 2006 New York</publisher>
      <isbn>9781933821276</isbn>
      <location>Adult</location>
      <collection>Non-fiction</collection>
      <callno>641.5 REA</callno>
      <status>Available</status>
   </item>

Comment: `//itemlist/item[contains(publisher, 'New York')]/(isbn|title)`. You might want to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath).